# Jsplumb dialog inserting data in react shapes

Tags: reactjs, jsplumb

I want to Insert data inside nodes shapes in jsplumb i have tried overlay property customs overlay but there are no examples available at google i want to achieve this i am using Reactjs Library.Is there any built in function in JsPlumb for inserting data inside shapes of JsPlumb or i need to write my own functions for that please answer me **Professionals**

Answer (score 0):

At which part of the diagram you need to put the data :

- at source/target elements or
- at the endpoint/connector of the connection ?

If you want to put the data at source/target elements, put them at the div elements which represent the source/target. Overlays are for endpoints and connectors.
Here is an example code :

```
    jsPlumb.ready(function () {
        var instance1 = jsPlumb.getInstance({
            //Container: "diagramcontainer",    
            PaintStyle:{ 
                strokeWidth:6, 
                stroke:"#567567", 
                outlineStroke:"black", 
                outlineWidth:1 
            },
            Connector:"Straight",
            Endpoint:[ "Dot", { radius:5 } ],
            EndpointStyle : { fill: "#567567"  },
            Anchors : [ "RightMiddle", "LeftMiddle" ],
        });

        instance1.connect({ 
            source:"manager1", 
            target:"supervisor1", 
            overlays: [
                ["Arrow", {location:1}],
                ["Label", {label:"Direct Connection with data", labelStyle: {fill: "skyblue", color: "white"}, id:"myLabel1"}]
            ],
        });


        var instance2 = jsPlumb.getInstance({
            //Container: "diagramcontainer",    
            PaintStyle:{ 
                strokeWidth:6, 
                stroke:"#567567", 
                outlineStroke:"black", 
                outlineWidth:1 
            },
            Connector:"Straight",
            Endpoint:[ "Dot", { radius:5 } ],
            EndpointStyle : { fill: "#567567"  },
            Anchors : [ "RightMiddle", "LeftMiddle" ],
        });

        let container = document.querySelector("#diagramcontainer")
        instance2.connect({ 
            source:"manager2", 
            target:"supervisor2", 
            overlays:[
                ["Custom", {                        
                    create:function(container) {                            
                        const el = document.createElement("input")
                        el.setAttribute("type","text")
                        el.setAttribute("value","Budget Flow")
                        el.setAttribute("readonly","")
                        return el
                    },
                    //location:0,
                    id:"customOverlay"
                }]
            ]               
        });
    });
```

React elements for source and target to render :

```
        <div id="diagramcontainer" ref={el => this.el = el} className="statemachine-demo" style={{height: "400px"}}>
            <div className="w" id="manager1"    style={{left: "10em", top: "12em", width: "10em", height: "5em"}}>
                Manager<p>Budget : 1000</p>
            </div>
            <div className="w" id="supervisor1" style={{left: "35em", top: "12em", width: "10em", height: "5em"}}>
                Supervisor<p>Budget : 5000</p>
            </div>

            <div className="w" id="manager2"    style={{left: "10em", top: "20em", width: "10em", height: "5em"}}>
                Manager<p>Budget : 1000</p>
            </div>
            <div className="w" id="supervisor2" style={{left: "35em", top: "20em", width: "10em", height: "5em"}}>
                Supervisor<p>Budget : 5000</p>
            </div>                
        </div>
```

The official documentation provides excellent explanation as well as some examples on using the library, [such as for overlay](http://jsplumb.github.io/jsplumb/overlays.html) .